# what will be the cause of redirection loop while accessing view settings page

Tags: views, caching, redirection

I have drupal 7.14 setup installed with views module.
Whenever i am trying to access "admin/structure/views" the 
site goes into redirection loop and not opening the views setting page also same behavior is showing for Linkit Profiles settings page.

I can add views by directly calling this url "/admin/structure/views/add" but not able to edit as they are not listing but i need to know why the views settings page not showing.

**Solutions which i already tried:**

- Uninstalled views module and again installed.
- run update.php
- cleared views cache from database

But it doesn't give me any result any guesses why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Five things I would check:

1. .htaccess rewrite rule?
2. Faulty alias? Check the table `url_alias` for any entry that contains `admin/structure/views`.
3. Redirect? If you have any redirect modules installed (globalredirect, redirect), check if there is a redirect set for the path in question.
4. Otherwise check the table `menu_router`, look for the path in the `path` column and see which function is set in the `page_callback` column. In D7 with Views 3 this should be `ctools_export_ui_switcher_page`.
5. Check your servers access and error logs to see if there's anything suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have jQuery Update module installed? I recently had some issues when editing views due to using a version of jQuery (1.9 I think) set by the jQuery Update module. What fixed it for me was installing the dev version of the module, which gives you the option of specifying a different version of jQuery - 1.5 in my case - to be used solely within the admin theme while at the same time using the more recent version for the rest of the site.